# Nutch : Unable to extract image urls using Nutch 1.12

Tags: java, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Nutch. I have installed Nutch 1.12 on my windows 10 64 bit machine a week back. I want to extract image URLs that matches XPath `//a[@class="product-link"]/img/@src` from http://www.myntra.com/men-tshirts. I have given the seed URL in the `seed.txt` file and edited my `regex-urlfilter.txt` as follows:

```
-\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
#-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
#-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# accept anything else
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*www.myntra.com/men-tshirts
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*assets.myntassets.com/
```

I have removed .jpg extension to not to ignore the image URLs that looks like "http://assets.myntassets.com/h_240,q_95,w_180/v1/image/style/properties/560433/ELABORADO-Men-Black-T-shirt_1_2010376f80fc4a65f4baac2f8c39082a_mini.jpg"

I also edited `suffix-urlfilter.txt` file and removed the `.jpg` extension from the prohibited extension list.

But I am unable to extract any image URLs in the end.

Here are steps that I followed:

1: bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls

2: bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments

3: s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`

4: bin/nutch fetch $s1

5: bin/nutch parse $s1

6: bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1

When I tried steps up to here and indexed the data to Solr
I am seeing only one document indexed and not seeing anything related to image URLs anywhere. Then I tried next round of the following steps

7: bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 1000

8: s2=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`

9: bin/nutch fetch $s2

After step 9, in the console, I am seeing no URL selected.

Can someone help me in understanding this problem and guide me towards how to extract the image URLs from the given seed URL???

Comment: Can someone please help me with this ???